# Cant display a msg below a text box

Tags: jsp

I have a for loop that displays multiple text box. When the user clicks on a button saying add more,the count increases by one and the text box is displayed. I am placing a div element under the text box and displaying a message under it using the id of that div from the script tags.

I seem to display the message under the first box only and not under the boxes generated by the for loop .I have the script tags in the for loops as well.

Please help me..

Comment: Plz. post your question properly and what is the first box ?  Put some of your code segment here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this,

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    var html = "";
    html = html + "<input type='text' class='sample' ><br>";
    html = html + "<div>sample text inside div</div>";
    $("#container").append(html);
});
```

I am really not sure about your question. See the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LmXsy/1/). Hope this helps. Post your code for getting answers exactly.